# Add a JOIN with a subquery into a views query

Tags: 7, database, views

[Here's my SQL](http://pastebin.com/RU2Ntte3), which I am trying to include in `hook_views_query_alter()` to modify the `uc_catalog` view (from Ubercart 3):

```
JOIN (
   SELECT uc_products.nid, MIN(uc_products.sell_price) AS min_price
   FROM uc_products
   JOIN node as n ON n.nid = uc_products.nid
   WHERE uc_products.nid IN
   (
     # in an ideal world, this is the WHERE statement from my views query
     SELECT ti.nid AS nid
     FROM taxonomy_index ti
     WHERE ti.tid = :db_condition_placeholder_1
     AND n.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2
     AND n.type IN :db_condition_placeholder_3
     GROUP BY uc_products.model
   )
 ) AS s2
 ON node.nid = s2.nid AND uc_products.sell_price = s2.min_price
```

I am confused as to how to make this work with the tools in [views_plugin_query_default](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins!views_plugin_query_default.inc/class/views_plugin_query_default/7) since this SQL has a subquery, etc. that is more complex than a simple `JOIN` statement.  I am having a hard time conceptualizing using `add_relationship` or `add_table` to make this work.  Is there something about `$join` building I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work this problem was solved with the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

Comment: can you explain detail?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi this is a project I worked on more than a year ago so I wouldn't be able to go into explicit detail. However, take a look at the View Field View module and whatever documentation/ community support you can find.  Basically, the module allows you to treat an entire view as a field in another view.  As you can imagine this is pretty powerful and helps you do something like what a JOIN statement would look like.

Comment: Although this may have solved your real-world needs perfectly, it doesn't actually answer the original question, i.e. "How do you join a subquery inside a Views query?"